# ValueError when running autopep8

Tags: python, python-3.x, linter, autopep8

I'm trying to run autopep8 recursively in a directory named "tests" with following command:

```
autopep8 --in-place --recursive tests
```

But I'm facing an odd error when running the command:

```
.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 819, in _get
    return conv(self.get(section, option, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'True'
```

I already tried other valid commands to try and run `autopep8` but none worked. How can I fix this issue?

[EDIT] Whole stack:

```
autopep8 tests --in-place --recursive --verbose
read config path: /home/acabista/Documents/automations/rainmaker/api-automation/tox.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/rainmaker-api/bin/autopep8", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/rainmaker-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4499, in main
    args = parse_args(argv[1:], apply_config=apply_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/rainmaker-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3835, in parse_args
    parser = read_config(args, parser)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/rainmaker-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4013, in read_config
    for norm_opt, k, value in _get_normalize_options(
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/rainmaker-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3970, in _get_normalize_options
    value = config.getint(section, k)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 834, in getint
    return self._get_conv(section, option, int, raw=raw, vars=vars,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 824, in _get_conv
    return self._get(section, conv, option, raw=raw, vars=vars,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/acabista/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 819, in _get
    return conv(self.get(section, option, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'True'
```

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: I'll update with the whole error stack, just a sec

Comment: I seems like autopep8 is reading a config file that has an unexpeted value (the string "True" instead of an integer). But its odd there isn't a better hint about which config file or what that option is.

Comment: It could be in /home/acabista/Documents/automations/rainmaker/api-automation/tox.ini

Comment: @tdelaney maybe, now I just have configurations in tox.ini for flake8, but I'll try to change it and check if something changes

Comment: @tdelaney yes, it was the tox.ini file, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autopep8 uses `configparser` to read .ini files. It expected to read an integer option but got the string `"True"` instead. Unfortunately, neither autopep8 or configparser are very good at telling you which option was bad. Potentially one could put a breakpoint in configparser to catch the error - you'll find that the erring line is in a try/except block and you can breakpoint the exception - but otherwise, manual inspection of the config file is due.